# Parametrized surface

Tags: differential-geometry

I am working in the exercise 7 section 2.3 of Shifrin book which says the following:

Decide whether there is a parameterized surface x(u,v) with $E=1, F=0, G=cos^2(u), l=cos^2(u), m=0, n=1$. Where E, F and G are the first fundamental form and I, m and n are the second one.

First at all I see if the Gaussian curvature are the same, because with the other exercises I got a contradiction, but in this case I have that the curvature is -1 in both cases.

When $k=\frac{ln-m^2}{EG-F^2}$ and with the formula that depends only of he first fundamental form.

So, I try to find the parametrization with the posible information of Xuu, Xuv, Xvu or Xvv but I don't get anything.

I'll be grateful if someone can give an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite follow your comment. The extrinsic formula for Gaussian curvature $K$ is $1$, not $-1$. The Gauss equation also gives you $K=1$. But have you checked whether the Codazzi equations hold? They are necessary in order for there to be (locally) a surface in $\Bbb R^3$ with these as first and second fundamental forms.